# Removing empty nodes from the RESULTING xslt transformation

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have the following requirement, I need to exclude the `<xlink:link>` if it's href attribute-, and the `<loc>` if it's value ends with ".xml" | ".xslt" | ".properties". This sometimes leaves me with the following. `<div ...></div>` Is there a way to remove these `<div ...></div>` as well in one go, or is there a need for consecutive processing?

Fragment of my input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1" xmlns:video="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <url>
        <loc id="843">en-us/system/xml/navigation.xml</loc>
        <xhtml:link href="/fr-fr/system/xml/navigation.xml" hreflang="fr-fr" rel="alternate"/>
        <xhtml:link href="/en-uk/system/xml/navigation.xml" hreflang="en-uk" rel="alternate"/>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc id="3159">/en-us/index.html</loc>
        <xhtml:link href="/fr-lu/index.html" hreflang="fr-lu" rel="alternate"/>
    </url>
</urlset>
```

My xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xpath-default-namespace="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1" xmlns:video="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" exclude-result-prefixes="video image xsl xhtml">
<xsl:output method="xhtml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- transform urlset -->
<xsl:template match="urlset">
    <div class="urlset"><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></div>
</xsl:template>

<!-- transform url -->
<xsl:template match="url">
    <div class="url"><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></div>
</xsl:template>  

<!-- transform the 'link' when valid -->
<xsl:template match="xhtml:link">
    <a><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></a>
</xsl:template> 

<!-- transform the 'loc' when valid -->
<xsl:template match="loc">
    <a>
        <xsl:attribute name="href">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
    </a>
</xsl:template>


<!-- transform the 'link' when not valid -->
<xsl:template match="xhtml:link[@href[ends-with(.,'.xml') or ends-with(.,'.xslt') or ends-with(.,'.properties')]]" /> 

<!-- transform the 'loc' when not valid -->
<xsl:template match="loc[ends-with(.,'.xml') or ends-with(.,'.xslt') or ends-with(.,'.properties')]" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

```
<div class="urlset">
   <div class="url"></div>  <=== *** I need to get rid of the likes of this ***
   <div class="url">
      <a href="/en-us/index.html" id="3159"></a>
      <a href="/fr-lu/index.html" hreflang="fr-lu" rel="alternate"></a>
   </div>
```

I've done a some searching for similar questions but they were all addressing the removal of empty nodes from the original document, not the resulting one.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add

```
<xsl:template match="url[every $node in (loc, xhtml:link/@href) satisfies (ends-with($node,'.xml') or ends-with($node,'.xslt') or ends-with($node,'.properties'))]"/>
```

then those `url` elements which have only `loc` and `xhtml:link/@href` with the endings you want to remove will not be transformed and will not create output. So with an approach like that you can do it in one step, I don't know whether there can be other content like `foo` elements present in `url` that also require the element to be transformed, but you can always write more complex conditions to cover that.

Comment: I can't edit your comment, but there is a missing ')' in `properties')]"/>`, it should be `properties'))]"/>`.

Works like a charm. Thank you.

"I don't know whether there can be other content like `foo` elements present in url that also require the element to be transformed, but you can always write more complex conditions to cover that." 
There can, but I have them covered.